# python plot frequency with continuous integer labeled x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make a frequency plot with special x-axis request based on the following pandas table.

```
     pos               freq
0     67                  1
1    285                  5
2    288                  1
3    397                  4
4    592                  1
5    640                  3
```

Since my frequency itself is for integers (pos column), I hope to have x-axis just with normal continuous numeric labels. However, with simple bar plot:

```
plot_pos=pos_freq.plot(kind='bar',x='pos')
```

I will only get x-axis labeled with 67, 285, 288, 397, 592, 640. Instead, I would like the x-axis be a series of continuous integers/intervals, e.g. 60, 65, 70, 75, ....645, 650; and that the frequency bars are still shown at the correct positions.

I'm not sure if bar plot is a good choice at this point, and I'm new to plotting in python. (I could do it in excel; Or I can probably add another x-axis...) Any suggestion for a better method is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `matplotlib`,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(pos_freq['pos'], pos_freq['freq'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the different options of plotting. Thank you for pointing out matplotlib module:)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
pos_freq.reindex(range(pos_freq['pos'].min(), pos_freq['pos'].max())).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Some further explanation will help!

Comment: Thank you @8one6, but I couldn't run your code - I think you may missed a ")" .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. it is a bit slow comparing with other methods though.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the x labels with pandas dataframe.plot() so I used matplotlib directly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ticks = range(0,700,5)  #this could whatever interval you wanted
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(pos_freq["pos"],pos_freq["freq"])
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
```

and you might want to make this a little bigger too with all those extra ticks

```
fig.set_size_inches(30,10.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and I really like the tricks you mentioned:)